# How to add existing sqlite database to Flutter and print as List of Cards?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, flutter, dart

I've searching very long for a solution to my problem. Many people have written something about adding an existing SQLite database to Flutter but not any of them has been exact.

So my question is how do I add an existing SQLite database (named `products.db`) in my Flutter application. I've already created the model class of the products and added an assets folder with the `products.db` file in it and of course I've edited the `pubspec.yaml` with the assets. 
Here is my `products.dart` model class:

```
class Products {

int _pid;
int _cid;
int _tid;
String _model;
String _description;
String _pictureURI;
double _price;

// Construktor
  Products(this._pid, this._cid, this._tid , this._model, this._description, this._pictureURI, 
  this._price);

// getters
int get id => _pid;
int get cid => _cid;
int get tid => _tid;
String get model => _model;
String get description => _description;
String get pictureURI => _pictureURI;
double get price => _price;

// setters dont needed

// Extract a Product Object from a Map Oject
Products.fromMapOject(Map <String,dynamic> map) {

this._pid = map['pid'];
this._cid = map ['cid'];
this._tid = map ['tid'];
this._model = map ['model'];
this._description = map ['description'];
this._pictureURI = map ['pictureURI'];
this._price = map ['price'];

 }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_db.md?

Comment: have tried exactyl this one [link](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md). In the output terminal it says "opening existing database" so i guess it is ok till this point but how do i have to read and save it in list cards to display the values in a List ? That's the point

Comment: Let me know if the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

@Soner624, assuming you followed [these](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_db.md) instructions and you have an instance of your products.db,

- create database functions to get your products (I don't have your database info so below is just an example to give you an idea. PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME = Your table name, COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID = your product id column name),

```
// Get product based on id
Future<Products> getProduct(Database assetDB, int id) async {
    final db = assetDB;
    var res = await db.query(PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME, where: COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID + " = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    Products product = res.isNotEmpty ? Products.fromMap(res.first) : null;
    return product;
}

// Get all products
Future<List<Products>> getAllProducts(Database assetDB) async {
    final db = assetDB;
    var res = await db.query(PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME);
    List<Products> list =
    res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => Products.fromMap(c)).toList() : [];
    return list;
}
```

- use it in your application (assuming **assetDB** is your products.db instance) to display list of products using Card widget,

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getAllProducts(assetDB),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              children: List.generate(snapshot.data.length, (itemIndex) {
                Products product = snapshot.data[itemIndex];
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: SizedBox(height: 50.0, width: 50.0, child: NetworkImage(product._pictureURI)),
                    title: Text(product._model),
                    subtitle: Text(product._description + ', ' + product._price),
                ));
              }),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        });
  }
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!